# Button won't postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, webforms, postback

How come my button refuses to do a postback in my super small learning ASP.Net MVC application?

***~/Blog/Post.aspx***

```
<h2>Post</h2>
<fieldset>
<legend>Blog message</legend>
<%using (Html.BeginForm())
  { %>
    <p>
        <label for="EntryTitle">Title:</label><br />
        <%= Html.TextBox("EntryTitle") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="EntryMessage">Message:</label><br />
        <%= Html.TextArea("EntryMessage") %>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" value="Post!" />
    </p>        
<%} %>
</fieldset>
```

***~/Controllers/BlogController.cs***

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Post(FormCollection collection)
    {            
        return View();
    }
```

I don't get it, what am I missing? :o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`.

Comment: We all do it! Glad to help. =)

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
<input type="submit" value="Post!" />
```